# Position an HTML element right under another as opposed to positioned to the right or left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, format

I have the following div styled and ready:
[image: my styled div]

everything is working according to plan EXCEPT the "like" button, which I have as a div with the current css (to ease in seeing the border, I have also added a green border for debugging):

```
.article-likes {
 margin-right: 16px;
 float: bottom;
 bottom: 8px;
 left: 5px;
 border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

and this is the html for the entire div.

```
<article class="media content-section">
<img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="/static/profile_pics/b1775e70284ad2de-1.png">
<!--- THE ELEMENT I AM TRYING TO MOVE IS DIRECTLY BELOW THIS LINE::::: --->
<div class="article-likes"><a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="">like</a></div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="article-metadata">
      <a class="mr-2" href="/user/1">1</a>
      <small class="text-muted">(me)  July 18, 2020 - 04:16 AM</small>
      <div style="float:right;" class="mr-2">
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-xs" href="/post/3">view</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h2><a class="article-title" href="/post/3">demo post</a></h2>
    
    <p class="article-content">demo post sorry</p>
    
  </div>
</article>
```

I am trying to get the like button positioned directly under (and slightly offset to the left) of the user image (profile picture). I have tried float:bottom; but this does not seem to stick the image to the bottom of the post. I have also tried adding margins but those end up messing the other elements in the article tag.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve (inside red rectangle is optimal placement):
[image: optimal element placement i am trying to achieve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use bootstrap you can simply wrap your image and like button inside `<div class="col"></div>`

and Voila! you have a column of contents, very simple.

Comment: Awesome, this works in putting it at the bottom, but it has the strange side effect of lengthening the like element an unforgivably long amount (so much so that it pushes the post content back rightwards a good couple of screen inches). Any way to stop that from happening?

Comment: ah, figured it out! I had to use the "extra small" column type (class='col-')

Answer (score 0):

Dude, I gotta say, your code is totally messed up. For God's sake, don't use such lengthy class names for such a simple code. And as I can see, you don't have basic knowledge about floating a div. Anyways, here is you answer. Just remove your css code and paste mine.

```
.article-likes {
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
 border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: This does not move the div below the image. It just resizes the bounding box? And if I use the bootstrap 'col' class, it does move it below, it has the same effect of pushing all other content (except the image) in the article to the right (as if the 'col' is too wide or something).

Comment: Well, I executed the code by myself and it went down, if it doesn't move down in your case, then just add display:block to the css and yes, please remove the float:right from this code. <div style="float:right;" class="mr-2">.

Comment: https://codepen.io/kiyubi/pen/JjGebbZ?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=0a68ed2fe4983e428e552120c0e26e2ff58bc731-1595049803-0-AYlKVrHLkHV3Gc4H2joIeyoCKlU9D90DGsxuQJ9PrPPscmgjxF11y1sgUVqwv5vR7L1c9M_OrK9-dufgQ8FVO8kYEBJp0DYIwpPxh3W-30x0C866aNbNYum6yrBV4AambeOiRIGEyS6eokxWIqJa2rMtjiUf0stUFcMQ1RN0B-etwfG7MSUVAfH1QA2IG62erH05mIZR7EwNwN6NxKWQpfPOa77W6WHLJlUWgg8vp_K3WMhFh2X8bR_a_CBUzQWINyn28gSlIhtctVnIA8AttO-yoFkB26lLevq4QTCQq2C6MSpZ6Ck0LVa_u6XqdVqZ04acYhOqsGCzxzcpHzc7_3U

Comment: its ok I figured out what I had to do (see other answer).

Comment: That's great !!